# Обрывается цикл на 7 странице, если начинать с 8, то проходит еще страниц 10 и опять падает

Tags: python, bs4

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

URL = 'https://mobistore.by/naushniki'
HOST = 'https://mobistore.by/'
HEADERS = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36'
}
def get_content(): 
    response = requests.get(url=URL, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    pages = int(soup.find('ul', class_='pagination').find_all('li')[-2].text)
    #проходимся по каждой странице и выбираем блок который будем парсить
    for page in range(1, pages + 1):
        list_url = f'https://mobistore.by/naushniki?page={page}'

        response = requests.get(url=list_url, headers=HEADERS)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

        items = soup.find_all('div', class_="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3")#блок
        spisok = []
        sleep(1)
        print(f'Парсим страницу №{page}')
        #собираем данные с конкретного блока
        for item in items:
            price = item.find('span', class_='price').get_text().split('\n')#блок с ценой разделяем на старую и новую цену
            spisok.append({
                'title': item.find('a', class_='product-name').get_text().strip().replace('\n', ''),
                'href': HOST + item.find('a', class_='image').get('href'),
                'number': item.find('div', class_='product-s-code').get_text(),
                'price_old': price[1],
                'price_new': price[4],
            })
        #записываем в json файл
        with open(f'data_{page}.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            json.dump(spisok, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False) 
            
def main():
    get_content()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: А посмотреть что не так на этих страницах религия не позволяет? А потому что в некоторых карточек цена не указана, то есть нет тега 'span' c классом 'price'

Comment: Бывает, не заметил, а в чем проблема без сарказма ответить, тоже религия не позволяет?

Comment: Однако это был риторический вопрос. Код выдает ошибку, как тут не заметить.

Comment: В любом случае, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```py
# код

spisok = []
for page in range(1, pages + 1):

    list_url = f'https://mobistore.by/naushniki?page={page}'
    response = requests.get(url=list_url, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3")

        for item in items:
            try:
                price=item.find('span',class_='price').get_text().split('\n')
            except AttributeError:
                continue
            spisok.append({
                'title': item.find('a', class_='product-name').get_text().strip().replace('\n', ''),
                'href': HOST + item.find('a', class_='image').get('href'),
                'number': item.find('div', class_='product-s-code').get_text(),
                'price_old': price[1],
                'price_new': price[4],
            })

# записываем в файл все данные в один json файл

with open(f'data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(spisok, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
# код
```